# Plug in / API for getting sea routes with leaflet

Tags: leaflet, routing, maritime-map

I am developing a maritime routing application prototype with Leaflet.js for my company Deep Blue Globe and using the windy interface.

The problem is since windy uses Leaflet version 0.7.7 there are not many routing APIs compatible with it and the one which is compatible doesn't provide sea routes.

So if anyone could suggest me something, any alternative it would be really helpful. Getting sea routes is of major importance here.

We want an interactive interface like windy (any alternatives to windy also welcome).

Comment: don't ships just sail in straight lines?

Comment: Yes they do, but the route might not always be a straight line. For example if a ship is sailing from Lisbon to Mumbai(a port in India) The route will not be a straight line. Also, I am using leaflet routing machine but when i try to get the easiest straight sea routes, it shows error message saying invalid route.